# How do I put together CSVs with matching names into one Workbook in Python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have CSVs with matching names  in two folders. They are unique i.e. for each record in Folder1, there is likely to be a matching record with same name in Folder2.

I would  like to combine  CSVs with matching  names into one workbook as Worksheets  within the  Workbook. For example, if  there exists 220001.csv in both Folder1 and Folder2, the resultant workbook would be  220001.xlsx in Folder3.  If a similar named file  is missing  in Folder2, then the  resultant .xlsx will just be with one worksheet i.e. the  record in Folder1. Folder1 is  the  master folder sort of.

How do I solve this in Python?

Comment: `resultant .xlsx will just be with one worksheet i.e. the record in Folder1` - you think  in `Folder3` will be excel sheet with one csv from `Folder1` ? Similar for `Folder2` ?

Comment: Yes, @jezrael .  resultant.xlsx will just  be file in Folder1 saved in Folder3 if, there is  no similar file in Folder2. Otherwise, resultant.xlsx will be a workbook with the values in the file in Folder1 in one Worksheet1 and  ones in Folder2 in the  worksheet2 with the  resultant.xlsx workbook saved in Folder3.

Comment: Seems duplicate of this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/42092263/10290248

Comment: Not exactly @ajayg2808 when it comes to finding  identical names of  CSVs in the  two folders. The example works to just combine  the csvs in the folder regardless of the names.  My example is to combine  only csvs  with identical names.

Comment: @Hummer You should do some effort with `os` and `os.path` library for finding same names, OR please show your code what you tried till now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
import os, glob

#get filenames from both folders
files1 = glob.glob('Folder1/*.csv')
files2 = glob.glob('Folder2/*.csv')

#create DataFrames
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(*os.path.split(x), x) for x in files1])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(*os.path.split(x), x) for x in files2])

#join together
df = df1.merge(df2, on=1, how='outer')

#for each row generate DataFrames and write to excel - if both match to 2 sheets
for x in df.itertuples():
    file = os.path.basename(x._2)
       
    m1 = pd.notna(x._3)
    m2 = pd.notna(x._5)
    if m1 and m2:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join('Folder33', x._2.replace('csv','xlsx')))
        df1 = pd.read_csv(x._3)
        df2 = pd.read_csv(x._5)
        df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=x._1)
        df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=x._4)
        writer.save()
    elif m1:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join('Folder33', x._2.replace('csv','xlsx')))
        df = pd.read_csv(x._3)
        df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=x._1)
        writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. Your solution works great and very well thought out  from my point. Only issue is regards records that are  present in Folder2 but missing in Folder1(master 1). They are still included in Folder3. Only formatting  issue is with the creation of an un named column in the final files in Folder3. All in all, its a clever solution. You're a legend.

Comment: @Hummer - So one thing - ouput folder of excels files are different? It means if match both to `Folder3`, if  match `Folder1` to `Folder1`? And values if exist in `Folder2` to `Folder2` ?

Comment: output  folder is Folder3.  Folder1 is  the "master". If filename in Folder1 matches a file name in Folder2, then the two are combined as in your solution and the result put in Folder3. If there is a file in Folder2 that doesn't match a file in Folder1, then its just left in Folder2 as it is. If a file in Folder1, doesn't match any in Folder2, then the folder1 file is put  in Folder3.  Folder1 files are the  main files. Hope  its a bit clear.

Comment: @Hummer - so need remove `elif` and `else` part of my solution?

Comment: @Hummer - For me not clear if file from `Folder1` not match with file `Folder2`, whats happen? Nothing? Or create excel file in `Folder1` ?

Comment: If file from Folder1 does not match any file in Folder2, then the file  in Folder1 is the only Worksheet in the resultant.xlsx. Its the opposite  for files in Folder2. If file in Folder2, does not  match a file in Folder1, then its just ignored. No resultant.xlsx for such a case. A bit clear?

Comment: @Hummer - Yes, but excel firl are written only in `Folder3` ? Or `If file from Folder1 does not match any file in Folder2, then the file in Folder1 is the only Worksheet in the resultant.xlsx.` - where is write excel? to `Folder1` or `Folder3` ?

Comment: Yes, the files are written only in Folder3.

Comment: Yes, its  writing to Folder3. Only small issue is in Folder2. If file is in Folder2 and not  in Folder1, then its also writing  to Folder3. It's not  supposed to write to that to Folder3. Should  just ignore.

Comment: @Hummer - Ok, `else` part was removed.

Comment: I just checked  and  @jezrael , it still writes the file in Folder2 to Folder3 when its  same file is not in Folder1.

Comment: @Hummer - You are right, answer was changed.

Comment: Thank you @jezrael. The updated answer works great.  I really appreciate  your input. You are a legend.

Comment: How can I get in touch with you @jezrael? Have some different  query.

Comment: @Hummer - I think best post new question, because a bit busy.

Comment: I came  across a question that is  close to what I was about  to put  up here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67277481/how-can-i-loop-through-and-increment-the-rows-in-an-excel-workbook-formula-in-py. Any good way around it?

Comment: @Hummer - I see, unfortunately no experience with `openpyxl`

Comment: Cool and I appreciate  your response.